# VS Code Showing Publish Branch Button When Branch Was Already Pushed

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlab

I used VS Code terminal to create a new branch, and then pushed the commit to GitLab. I've confirmed on my GitLab account that the branch was successfully pushed but VS Code is still showing a `Publish Branch` button.
When I execute `git status` in the terminal, i receive the response: `nothing to commit, working tree clean`.

I've tried restarting VS Code and running `git fetch` but the `Publish Branch` button is still showing. I have not yet clicked on the `Publish Branch` button because I don't know what it will do and I've already sent a merge request for this branch. Does anyone have any recommendation on how I should go about resolving this minor but annoying issue?

Answer (score 12):

I believe the issue is that you don't have upstream tracking set up, because I ran into the same issue and just fixed it about 5 minutes ago.  So first of all, to fix your existing issue, I believe all you need to do is this.

`git branch --set-upstream-to origin/branchname`

This just sets up upstream tracking for your branch, which should fix your existing problem.

The rest of this post is just quickly walking through the whole process from creating a new branch to pushing it.  So first, switch to the correct branch.

`git checkout branchname`.

If you haven't created the branch yet, you would instead do `git checkout -b branchname` to create the new branch.

Then make whatever changes you're going to make, and then add the changed files to the staging area.

`git add .`

And then commit the changes

`git commit -m "commit message"`

And then (and I believe this is where you ran into the issue), when you're ready to push your changes, you need to run this:

`git push -u origin branchname`

I think that you just forgot the -u, which is an option that sets up upstream tracking for your branch.  Once I did that, the "Publish Branch" button went away.  I know this was asked a month ago so you probably figured it out quite a while ago, but hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue also. The solution was to add the fetch entrry to the remote origin in git config

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

complete file

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https:****************
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```